# Create a macro that runs another macro based on the value of another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am wanting to create a macro "Conditional" that will run a macro "FillOneOver" (already created) if the value of the cell 42 cells to the right of the selected cell is greater than 1 otherwise it will run "FillBack1" (already created).  Either of the two already created macros will end up by selecting the cell directly below the original selected cell (ready to run "Conditional" again).  I want to be able to move through my spreadsheet one cell at a time vertically based on criteria horizontally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In your VBE's Project pane, double click the worksheet/tabname on which this cell resides.
2. At the top of the pane where you write code there are two drop down boxes. Select "Worksheet" in the first one and "Change" in the second.
3. A new subroutine is generated in the coding pane that looks like:

   ```
   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

   End Sub
   ```

   This subroutine will execute automatically every time any cell changes on this worksheet. `Target` will hold the range/cell that changed so we can test `Target` to see if its the cell you care about, what it's value is, and call the appropriate subroutine.
4. Assuming the cell that has the value you care about is `A1` then the code may look something like:

   ```
   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
       'Using "Intersect" to determine if A1 has changed
       If Not (Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing) Then
           If Target.Value > 1 Then
               Call Macro2
           Else
               Call Macro3
           End If
       End If
   End Sub
   ```

Now go change the value in `A1` and the appropriate subroutine/macro should be called.

Comment: I am not so familiar with VBE is there a way that I can create a macro for this.  I think I will need to use the "offset" since I the target cell is constantly changing and I am working on a large spreadsheet and need to move through it quickly.

Comment: @LorenS `I am not so familiar with VBE`???? VBE, Visual Basic Editor.  It is where you write the code.  JNevill is just saying that you put his code in the worksheet code and not a module.

Comment: "Macro" is synonymous with a "Subroutine", they are the same thing. I assume you mean, "Is there a way I can record a macro for this", the answer is "No". This will require some familiarity of VBA coding especially if your target cell is moving. That being said, besides the Worksheet Change event, there is a Worksheet Double Click event that will fire whenever you double click a cell. Perhaps you could just double click your target, and just copy and paste this code into that doubleclick sub. This would be worth struggling through to get working, although I totally get the frustration.

Comment: Why not use `Worksheet_SelectionChange`? It will run whenever you click on a new cell

Comment: @DaBeau96 Sounds fine to me. OP didn't specify when they want it to run, so I figured I would go with _change. 6 of one, half a dozen of the other.

Comment: @DaBeau96 SelectionChange is indiscriminate. as you will need other test to ensure that the wrong cell is not causing false positives.  DoubleClick would probably be the best.

Comment: Like JNevill said they ddin't specfiy when they wanted the code to run or really how they wanted it to work. I gave them the starting code and if they find problems they can always try and figure out the solution to the issue. Learning by doing is always a good option in my eyes.

Comment: I edited the question to provide more specifically what I am wanting to do

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
 If Target.Cells.Count < 2 Then 'Checks to see if more than one cell is selected
  If Target.Value <> Empty Then 'Is the cell empty
   If IsNumeric(Target) = True Then 'Is the cell a number
    If Target.Value > 1 Then 'Is the value greater than 1
     macro2 'runs macro2
   Else
     macro3 'runs macro3
   End If
  End If
 End If
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This will run macro2 if a cell has text in it also.  You may want to put a few more checks in.

Comment: Now it checks to see if there is a value and if the value is a number before running

Comment: my only concern now is if the OP selects a cell with a number and it is not the one that is supposed to trigger the macros.  Say B1 is the cell that is the test as to which to trigger, and the user select B3 which has a number, the code will fire.  You need to add something that checks which cell is being selected to ensure the correct cell.

Comment: They didn't really say how they wanted it to work and I know user error can be a problem, but I gave them the frame and they can go and figure out where they need to fix issues or potential errors. Learning by doing is usually a good option